# Does the argument list pass the string quotes to exec command in C?

Tags: c, string, grep, execvp

I am using `execvp` for execing a new process for the command `grep -l night *`. Here is my code:

```
char * argument[5];
char keyword[] = "night";

argument[0] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*25);
argument[1] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*25);
argument[2] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*25);
argument[3] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*25);
argument[4] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*25);

argument[0] = "grep";
argument[1] = "-l";
strcpy(argument[2],keyword);
argument[3] = "*";
argument[4] = NULL;

execvp ("grep", argument);
```

But I am getting the output from this program as "grep: *: No such file or directory" 
which is incorrect as executing the same command from the shell results in the list of 
files which contain the text "night". I do suspect that the `*` in the command list is being
sent as a string with quotes to `exec`. Is my assumption correct? If so how can I rectify this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that your code is leaking memory; you allocate space, but then you ignore the allocated space with the assignments.  You have to use `strcpy()` or something similar to use the allocated memory.  Of course, there's no great harm done; the `execvp()` will clean up for you, and the exit that occurs after it if the command fails altogether also cleans up.  But don't get into the habit of throwing memory away as you do - it will hurt you in due course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep does not understand the "*" argument. Usually the shell expands such arguments (it's called [*globbing*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)). Of course, since `exec` functions don't start a shell, you don't get that functionality.

You can:

- Use functions which *do* start a shell (`system(3)`, `popen(3)`)
- Use [`glob(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/glob.3.html), essentially doing the shells job

#### EDIT

You could probably write it as this (**untested**):

```
glob_t globbuf;
globbuf.gl_offs = 3;

/* Globbing magic. */
glob("*", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);

/* That's what the 3 was for. */
globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "grep";
globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-l";
globbuf.gl_pathv[2] = "night";

/* Conveniently, the list is NULL-terminated. */
execvp("grep", globbuf.gl_pathv);
```

Comment: shouldn't the `[1] = "night"` be `[2] = "night"`?

Comment: Thanks guys, both popen and glob are working.
Is there any thing as to mark this question as closed/answered? I am new to asking questions here.