# Using execlp system call with shell metacharacters in the arguments in C

Tags: c

Program : List all C files in the current folder using `execlp()` system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Before Execl\n");
    execlp("ls","ls","*.c",NULL); // this should print all c files in the current folder.
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Before Execl
ls: cannot access *.c: No such file or directory
```

Whenever I use '`*`' in the search pattern, I am getting a similar kind of error. Please suggest some appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want shell metacharacters expanded, invoke the shell to expand them, thus:

```
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "ls *.c", (char *)0);
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec /bin/sh (%d %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Note that if `execl()` or any of the `exec*` functions returned, it failed.  You don't need to test its status; it failed.  You should not then do `exit(0);` (or `return 0;` in the `main()` function) as that indicates success.  It is courteous to include an error message outlining what went wrong, and the message should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout` — as shown.

You can do the metacharacter expansion yourself; there are functions in the POSIX library to assist (such as [`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html)).  But it is a whole heap simpler to let the shell do it.

(I've revised the code above to use `execlp()` to conform to the requirements of the question.  If I were doing this unconstrained, I'd probably use `execl()` and specify `"/bin/sh"` as the first argument instead.)

Comment: Note that if you forked before calling `execlp`, any use of `stdio` operations in the child is probably wrong, unless you're sure that (1) the program is single-threaded, and (2) the child's copy of `stderr` (or whichever `FILE` you are using) is qualified to become the "active handle" (see POSIX XSH 2.5.1). Personally I would just avoid any use of non-async-signal-safe functions following `fork`, which also includes `exit`; use `_Exit` instead.

Comment: That [XSH §2.5.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) is a complicated way of saying "If you program normally, you will be OK".  In particular, `stderr` is normally unbuffered, and gets the "no action need be taken" OK on the third bullet.

Comment: Well being normally unbuffered is an implementation detail. As I recall, the standards just say that it shouldn't be fully buffered by default, so having `stderr` line buffered by default is probably conformant for an implementation and might give significantly better performance. I would call `fflush(stderr)` before forking if you intend to use it in both parent and child after the fork, just to be safe...

Answer (score 0):

Exec does not handle the "`*`" operator as the shell does it for you. Use `popen()` or `glob_t` for this. You can 
get more details on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625225/does-the-argument-list-pass-the-string-quotes-to-exec-command-in-c) which I asked on 2012-03-08.

Comment: Why `popen()`?  You aren't about to write to the `ls` command, or read its output, so why would you benefit from a pipe?  The `glob_t` you mention is a type associated with the [`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) function.

Answer (score -1):

Should it be:

```
   execlp("ls", "*.c", NULL);
```

Comment: No; that does not help; the shell does the metacharacter expansion, not the `exec*` system calls.

Answer (score -1):

```
execlp("ls", "*.c", NULL);
```

should work

Comment: Sorry, that does not help.  The shell does the metacharacter expansion, not the `exec*` system calls.